# Is it possible to get fcurves associated to a bone by script ?

Tags: python, animation, scripting, fcurves, actions

I'm working on a Blender add-on for transfering animation. I'd like to know if there's a way to select the fcurves describing a bone's movement through the bone.

What I mean is that the only way to access fcurves that I know so far is: 
`bpy.data.objects['Armature'].animation_data.action.fcurves` and I wish to know whether there is something like `bpy.data.objects['Armature'].pose.bones['MyBone'].fcurves`.

Alternatively, I could settle for a way to know the curve's bone name.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Looks like this may have been answered: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/58921/32655